Identify movie about special/secret agents
It's an American movie from the 90's or 2000-something.
Roughly it has two main characters a man and woman. They are to be formed as secret agent. I only remember one passage: they are both kidnapped and sequestrated by an unknown group of men. These men try to mentally and physically break them. Finally it turns out that it was part of their training as special agents and that all that time they were in fact imprisoned in a container in a big hall where the other 'students' could follow their ordeal. 

I think this is The Recruit (IMDB here)

A brilliant young CIA trainee is asked by his mentor to help find a mole in the Agency. 


Hi. Welcome to Stack Exchange! Could you please add a description of why you think this movie answers the question? A short synopsis of the movie should be fine.

duckndive has it nailed, welcome to M&TV. Good Entrance ;) try to 'show your working out' here though, if possible.
